# attr('id') returns empty string

Tags: jquery

I am trying to iterate through all form elements. Here's my code:

```
$.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(fsai,fsae) {             
    alert($(fsae).attr('name'));
});
```

This works well; and I get all alerts with all field's names. But I need to get IDs. So I do it this way:

```
$.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(fsai,fsae) {             
    alert($(fsae).attr('id'));
});
```

This one never works. All I get is an empty alert. Why?

PS: All elements have valid name and id attributes with valid values.

Here's the Markup:

```
<form>
    <input id="e90" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" value="">
    <textarea placeholder="Comments" id="e91" name="comments" type="" value=""></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="e92" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please check Question Edit.

Comment: I think it is not possible to get the ID. http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

Comment: i have post an answer, as an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sadikhasan says jQuery serializeArray will return name and value pair so you cannot access id.

So you try like this

```
//Get all input elements in form
$("form :input").each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});

//It will be better if form has some id or class
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxk3F/1923/)

Comment: what about <textarea> and other non-<input> elements?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery **serializeArray** will return name and value pair so you cannot access id. Check [Manual](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `".prop()"` instead of `".attr()"`

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If Id attribute exists for the element then you can directly access id attribute like

```
$.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(fsai,fsae) {             
    alert($(fsae).id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var tes = $('form');

var children = tes.children();

   $(children).each(function () 
   {
       var TAG = $(this).get(0).tagName;

       if(TAG != "DIV" && TAG != "SPAN")
       {
           alert($(this).attr("id"));
           alert($(this).attr("name"));
           //u can push each element atrribute like name or id here to an array.
       }
   });
```

note that this is just work around, but it's working, here is the working example [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hho6k86a/3/)

just like @REX said, it will be better if ur form have an ID, coz ur document might have more than 1 form at the same time.

Comment: Can this make sure if not other elements are included in loop (like divs, spans etc)

Comment: @aceph i have edited my post, it's checking the html tag, it won't alert id and name if the element is a div or a span.